# Realtime and Offline voice recognition?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

Most voice recognition solutions on Android seem to rely on remote servers. I'm interested in allowing the player to issue simple "left", "right" and "turn back" commands to a vehicle. The recognition would need to be very fast (internet is thus out of the question), but only needs to be able to distinguish between three commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question!

This can be achieved by implementing a few things:

- Catching an `InputStream`
- Handling the audio
- A Recognizer with Grammar and your Words (up, down, left, right, jump)
- A Parser

This project will be quite useful to you:

http://code.google.com/p/tellmeajoke/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc

EDIT: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=743679 other applications may handle it differently, but the example above is one way to do it.

Comment: Will it work offine voice reconization